# Associative and anticommutative Binary Operation(composition)

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, associativity

Show that if binary operation ,$\Delta$, is associative and anticommutative on $\mathbb{E}$, then $x\Delta y \Delta z=x\Delta z$ ∀$x,y,z \in \mathbb{E}$. [Hint: consider $x\Delta y\Delta z\Delta x\Delta z$]

Answer (score 0):

Since $\Delta$ is associative and anticommutative we have $\Delta$ is idempotent and $x \Delta y \Delta x=x$ ∀$x,y \in \mathbb{E}$ see [Associative Binary Operation(composition) is anticommutative iff idempotent...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124048/associative-binary-operationcomposition-is-anticommutative-iff-idempotent)

∴  we right multiply $x \Delta y \Delta x=x$ by $y,z,x,z$ in that order.

This yields  $x \Delta y \Delta x\Delta y\Delta z\Delta x\Delta z=x\Delta y\Delta z\Delta x\Delta z$ $\Longrightarrow$ $(x \Delta y \Delta x)\Delta y(\Delta z\Delta x\Delta z)=(x\Delta( y\Delta z)\Delta x)\Delta z$  $\Longrightarrow$ $x\Delta y \Delta z=x\Delta z$

QED